# show ads from a banner exchange

Tags: javascript, html, css

In order to show ads from a banner exchange, I'm loading a webview containing an iframe linking to the ads server. Through some javascript I can have the ad link targer to be "_blank" so the ad would open in a separate browser window, otherwise it would open in the same small webview.

However it doesn't work and I get this in the console:

```
<webview>: A new window was blocked.
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call `updateData()` you are deleting the current SVG and adding a new one.
`d3.select('.' + value)` returns the SVG node currently in the DOM, so setting an attribute of it is temporary, just until you delete it and add a new one.

Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/T6G5Z/) updated fiddle.

I added a global `visibleCharts` object that I change when the checkboxes change and use these values on each `updateData()` call.

You could also skip the whole on('click') and global `visibleCharts` mechanism and just check if the checkboxes are checked directly in the `updateData()` function.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you have inverted focus1 and focus2. Check out this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/T6G5Z/1/.